# How to copy every line from a file to MS Word using nano

Tags: files, libreoffice, file-format

I would like to copy every line and character from a file to Microsoft Word or another word processor. However, when I select all the text with nano text editor and paste it to LibreOffice Word, all the formatting is messed up, which makes the difficult to understand. Is there anyway I copy all the lines, or save or download the file in a  way so that I could open it in a word processor with the formatting intact?

Comment: Try using a graphical text editor like `Gedit` to copy the text you want to paste in LibreOffice. Or Open LibreOffice and then use the File > Open dialogue to open the text file directly.

Comment: Just right click on the file and choose open with other application and choose Libreoffice. No need to such between two apps.

Comment: Nano is not the right tool for that job.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you copying text around? Just open the file using libreoffice. From the command line:

`libreoffice someFile`

Comment: So I typed the command for my file but the formatting was entirely messed up. https://imgur.com/a/KCQdOeV Is there anyway to rectify this?

Comment: what does the original text file look like? Can you make a simple text file with just some junk text from a lorem ipsum generator, then try that?

Comment: @NicholasProietti Looks like the original text is far wider (more columns) than fit on a standard A4 (or Letter or whatever format) sheet.

Comment: Do you know another word processor that could format the orginal text well, or if I could change the settings in LibreOffice for this?

Comment: you should take the advice that everyone is giving to you